# Display information from associated table?

Tags: php, sql

I am running this statement which works fine....

```
$sql = "SELECT skill,SUM(quantity) as sum FROM skills
WHERE userid = $userid
GROUP BY skill";
```

My problem is the column skill stores the value from table agency_skills which has a column that contains the name of the skill.

I am trying to figure out how to display the name of the skill rather than the value stored in the skills table?

This is the entire code I am working with.....

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$userid = $user->get('id');


$sql = "SELECT skill,SUM(quantity) as sum FROM skills
WHERE userid = $userid
GROUP BY skill";

$db->setQuery($sql);

$rows = $db->loadObjectList();

?>
<style>
table, td, th
{
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
    {
    th
background-color:#000000
color:#FFF
    }


</style>

<table>
<tr>
<th width="195">Skill</th> <th width="195">Total Completed</th>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<?PHP foreach ($rows as $row): ?>

<tr>

<td width="200"> <?php echo $row->skill?> </td>

<td width="190"> <?php echo $row->sum ?> </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can join that table like this

```
SELECT as.skillname,
       SUM(s.quantity) as sum 
FROM agency_skills as `as`
left outer join skills as s on s.skill = as.id
WHERE s.userid = $userid
GROUP BY as.skillname
```

If you use a `left outer join` instead of the default `inner join` you get even `skill`s that are not present in the `skills` table.

[Simplified SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19a8c/2)

Comment: I think you meant SELECT as.skillname or whatever the field is called to get the name of the skill vs the id.  Other than that, great answer!

Comment: Could be. It is not quite clear what the fields are called. Maybe the OP can bring some light to that?

Comment: Table "skills" ---> Columns---> id, date_time, clinicalid, skill, quanity, userid...... "skill" has an equivelent to the second table's id... the second table is "agency_skills---> Columns ---> id, date_time, skillname, required, courses.... the id of agency skills should = skill

Comment: I did try the above code which did not appear to work.... However I did try to fiddle with it a little bit.... I am having trouble completely understanding it..... not sure of the s. and as.

Comment: @JoshuaBlevins: I changed my answer according to your table structure.

Comment: I tried this as well no luck received this error......#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'left outer join skills s on s.skill = as.id GROUP BY as.skillname LIMIT 0, 30' at line 4

Comment: @JoshuaBlevins: You're right. I forgot to escape `as`. Fixed now.

Comment: I am going to post an image on my server to help explain this since I cannot post it here since I have not been on the site long enough [link](http://ems-complete.com/clincial_skills.png) I hope this will better explain the setup and intended output address to pic http://ems-complete.com/clinical_skills.png

Comment: @JoshuaBlevins: Isn't my answer working? See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19a8c/2)

Comment: I really do appreciate all the help you have been, I placed the code and all works great..... I did some studying around the code that you wrote and I now understand it my self. I have another question that I will be adding soon I hope that you will be of assistance there as well this one will be about changing date and time in a select statement.... Thank You very much.